# Rewriting with context in nested expressions (congruence rules)

Tags: lean, lean4

I am trying to prove the following example in Lean 4:

```
-- defining my own version of List.contains, because I could not figure out how 
-- to use the equality type class used in the existing one
def List.contains' (x: A): List A → Prop
  | [] => False
  | (y::ys) => x = y ∨ ys.contains' x

example
  {l: List Nat}
  {f: Nat → Nat}
  (h: ∀ (x: Nat), l.contains' x → (f (f x) = f x))
  : l.map (λx => f (f x)) = l.map (λx => f x)
  := by
    simp [h] -- fails
```

This example works without the `l.contains' x` precondition in `h`, but with the precondition it seems the context is missing.

My question is how I can teach Lean to do this rewrite automatically?

### For context:

I am coming from Isabelle, where this example is simply:

```
theorem example: 
  assumes ‹∀x∈set l. f (f x) = f x›
  shows ‹map (λx. f (f x)) l = map (λx. f x) l›
  using assms by simp
```

### What I tried so far:

#### Try 1

Since Isabelle uses congruence rules to guide the simplifier for nested terms, I tried to define a congruence rule in Lean as well:

```
@[congr]
def map_congr'
  {f g : A → B}
  {xs ys : List A}
  (h1: xs = ys)
  (h2: ∀(x: A), xs.contains' x → f x = g x)
  : xs.map f = ys.map g
  := sorry
```

However, this rule was not picked up by the `simp`, `rw`, or `conv` tactic.

Only manually applying worked:

```
example
  {l: List Nat}
  {f: Nat → Nat}
  (h: ∀ (x: Nat), l.contains' x → (f (f x) = f x))
  : l.map (λx => f (f x)) = l.map (λx => f x)
  := by
    apply map_congr' (xs := l)
    · exact show l = l from rfl
    · exact h
```

#### Try 2

Next, I tried to define a version of `map` that makes the fact that `l.contains' x` available in the function `f`:

```
def List.map' : (l: List A) → (f: (x: A) → l.contains' x → B) → List B
  | [], f => []
  | (x::xs), f =>
      have c1: (x::xs).contains' x := by simp [List.contains']
      f x c1 :: map' xs (fun y p =>
        have c2: (x::xs).contains' y := by simp [List.contains', p]
        f y c2)
```

I was expecting that this lets me use the `rw` or `simp` tactic, but again it failed:

```
example
  {l: List Nat}
  {f: Nat → Nat}
  (h: ∀ (x: Nat), l.contains' x → (f (f x) = f x))
  : l.map' (λx p => f (f x)) = l.map' (λx p => f x)
  := by
      rw [h] -- tactic 'rewrite' failed, did not find instance of the pattern in the target expression
```

It worked with the `conv` tactic, but my feeling is that there is an easier way to do this.

```
example
  {l: List Nat}
  {f: Nat → Nat}
  (h: ∀ (x: Nat), l.contains' x → (f (f x) = f x))
  : l.map' (λx p => f (f x)) = l.map' (λx p => f x)
  := by
      conv =>
        pattern (λx p => f (f x))
        intro x
        intro p
        rw [h x p]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see your congruence theorem is being applied using `set_option trace.Debug.Meta.Tactic.simp true`, but by default `simp` does not dynamically extend the context during traversal with local facts such as from `xs.contains' x → _`. You can tell it to do so via

```
by simp (config := { contextual := true }) [h]
```

or you can use the "heavy-weight" `by simp_all` that does both contextual simplification as well as simplification of assumptions via other assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to set this as a default? I would also like to use this congruence in a termination proof. Are there similar options on `termination_by`? (the termination proof is for a function on a tree, where the recursive call is inside a `map` over the children of a node).

Comment: There is no option to change the default currently, though you could wrap that in a new tactic like in https://gist.github.com/Kha/91614b6149561750d77ba5ad0739c7ba. Well-founded termination does not have a concept of something like these congr rules yet, the usual workaround is to make it an explicit mutual recursion https://github.com/Kha/lean4/blob/4b03666eccad726d459cdb9dd6034f0089f60aaa/tests/lean/run/mut_ind_wf.lean#L58-L69.